# How to send an email using GSUITE group id thorugh GMail API?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, gmail-api, google-workspace

Currently I am working on a request, where I need to send an email from GSuite group id using GMail API. I am able to send an email using my personal account. I want to avoid the alias and use that same group email id to send emails through my code.

```
final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

GoogleCredential credential1 = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH));

GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
.setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
.setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
.setServiceAccountId(credential1.getServiceAccountId())
.setServiceAccountPrivateKey(credential1.getServiceAccountPrivateKey())
.setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
.setServiceAccountUser("gsuitegroupemail@DOMAIN.COM")
.build();

Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY,credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();

MimeMessage mimeMessage = CreateMessage.createEmail("sourav.lion@DOMAIN.com",
"gsuitegroupemail@DOMAIN.COM", "TestGmailApi", "TestEmail");

App.sendMessage (service, "gsuitegroupemail@DOMAIN.COM", mimeMessage);
```

Whenever I am trying to perform this I am facing '401 unauthorized' error. Here is the stacktrace for the same.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:394)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:868)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
at com.globalpayments.gmailapi.GMailApi.App.sendMessage(App.java:83)
at com.globalpayments.gmailapi.GMailApi.App.main(App.java:51)
```

Comment: Is G Suite Domain Wide Delegation enabled? That is required.

Comment: Could you please let me know how to do that?

Comment: What are your scopes? Also, are all your credentials/token up-to-date? It could be that your token has expired. Can you please post your Stacktrace?

Comment: I have added the StackTrace and As I am using a Service Account with domain wide delegation I don't think maintaining a token is necessary

Answer (score 0):

*The issue with the `401 Unauthorized` error is it can come from a few different sources. Here is a rundown of the more common reasons.*

#### The First Step:

Before continuing, double-check that you have the Gmail API<sup>[[1]](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api)</sup> enabled in the Developer's console<sup>[[2]](http://console.developers.google.com/)</sup> ***for the project that you are using*** - it is possible that either it was enabled for a different project or even that it was accidentally turned off while crawling through settings.

Once at the Developer's console select your project from the drop-down in the top-left of the page next to the `Google APIs` before checking the API is enabled.

#### Debugging `401 Unauthorized`:

The specific error `TokenResponseException: 401 Unauthorized` can also come from an expired access token. While this doesn't have to be maintained for Service Accounts in the same way it does for user account access to the APIs, it does get generated on-the-fly and will depend on the credential file you are using.

The important things to remember for the credentials is that your service account email and your scopes have to be well and completely defined; that is to say, **the scopes you are using give your application access to the services it is trying to access**. In the case of the Gmail `Users.messages: send`<sup>[[3]](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send)</sup> method you will need one of the following scopes:

- https://mail.google.com/
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send

**Note:** it is also important to make sure that you have the scopes available for the other methods in the application that you wish to use. Check out the method-specific pages for this information.

Also check out Google's API management page detailing how to authenticate with a service account in Java<sup>[[4]](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/service-account-authentication)</sup> for more information.

#### Service Accounts and Domain-Wide Delegation:

As per the Google documentation, it is important to give the service account you are using to access your user data domain-wide delegation of authority<sup>[[5]](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation)</sup>. The steps are provided in reference #5 but the run-down is as follows:

> To enable G Suite domain-wide delegation, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Locate the newly-created service account in the table. Under **Actions**, click **⋮** then **Edit**.
> 2. In the service account details, click **˅ Show domain-wide delegation**, then ensure the **Enable G Suite Domain-wide Delegation** checkbox is checked.
> 3. If you haven't yet configured your app's OAuth consent screen, you must do so before you can enable domain-wide delegation. Follow the on-screen instructions to configure the OAuth consent screen, then repeat the above steps and re-check the checkbox.
> 4. Click **Save** to update the service account, and return to the table of service accounts. A new column, **Domain-wide delegation**, can be seen. Click **View Client ID**, to obtain and make a note of the client ID.

#### Getting More Information out of the `401`:

It might also be possible to get more detailed information about the specifics of your `401` by extracting data from the HTTP response:

```java
try {
    App.sendMessage (service, "gsuitegroupemail@DOMAIN.COM", mimeMessage);
} catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
    // log your errors and error messages
}
```

#### References:

1. [Gmail API v4](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api)
2. [Google Developer's Console](http://console.developers.google.com/)
3. [Gmail API - `Users.messages: send` Method](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send)
4. [Authenticating with a service account](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/service-account-authentication)
5. [Perform G Suite Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation)

Comment: Whenever I am using my personal id I am able to send the mail but when I am changing it to gsuite group id it is throwing '401 unauthorised'.. even after try catch block I am getting the same StackTrace

Comment: Added domain-wide delegation information to my answer

Comment: @SouravChatterjee i have the same problem, any news about it?

Comment: @moxched I did reach out to Google and as per them we cannot use service accounts/GSuite group ids for GMAIL API as these accounts don't have any Gmail box associated with them.